# Owl-Carousel Reponsive Text within One Slide example

Tags: owl-carousel

Would anyone have a working code example of how to set up responsive text with a slide item?

More specifically the 'One Slide' demo.

Example

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item">
    <h3>Sample Heading within Text</h3>
    <p>Content and text within slide</p>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
</div>
</div>
```

Would you set up a class for the  or wrap everything in a div?

Able to setup for desktop, but gets interesting when viewing on mobile.

Thanks.